# How can I send the variables from android environment into JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webpage which is loaded into webview and inside loadUrl method there is a JavaScript function, which changes the links inside the webpage. If I write the JS code in loadUrl as a single string, it works well. But I need to change the links dynamically, so I need to get the variables from android code into my JS code inside loadUrl method.

I've tried to concatenate the JS code with my String from my Activity, it doesn't work.

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:" +
        "document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => link.href =" +
        myString + ")")
```

Comment: Have you tried adding some quotes for javascript? cf `link.href ='" + myString + "')"` or `link.href =\"" + myString + "\")"`? because or else it would interpret the content of your variable as a litteral expression instead of a string

Comment: Yes, seems I forgot to add quotes, thanks! Now

Comment: But if I pass a String, made by concatenation of other Strings, it doesn't work again.

Comment: Have you checked that `myString` doesn't have quotes in it? you would need to escape them to make it work